# Select query not working with post array with duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, select, implode

My user post an array of categories, then I need to select  rates from a table based on the array of categories that the user selected.
So far I have been able to get this to work fine.

Example:

Array Categories: Auto Parts, Bicycles, Biscuits, Ceiling Fans, Blenders, Artwork

Returned Array Rates: 60, 35, 25, 20,15, 5

Then I do calculations based on the rates selected in the rate array. The code i have below works fine if there is no duplicate values in array.

The problem I am having is if the user inputs a category twice the returned array is only returning the rate for one instance of the inputted category

Example:

Array Categories: Auto Parts, Bicycles, Biscuits, Ceiling Fans, Bicycles, Blenders, Biscuits, Artwork

Returned Array Rates: 60, 35, 25, 20, 15, 5

what it should be-> Array Rates: 60, 35, 25, 20, 35, 15, 25, 5

The array being returned is dropping the duplicate rate values but i need to do the calculations based on the rate in each row of the the returned array.

I don't now how to make that returned value stay in the returned array. any help would be great or any suggestion of another way I can do this.

```
 $qty=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qty'];
 $pcategories=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pcategories'];

 <?php foreach($qty as $a => $b){ ?>

 <?php // Get the duty rate based on the product categorie user selected 
   $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","customs") or  `enter
    code here`die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$sql = "
    SELECT `categories`, `rate`
    FROM `lt_products`
      WHERE `categories` IN ('".implode("','",$pcategories)."')
        ORDER BY FIELD(categories, '".implode("','",$pcategories)."')";
         $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $row_rate[] =  $row["rate"];
 } 
     $rate_row[] = $row_rate[$a];
 ?>
```

Comment: You can use array_unique http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php method to get unique values from array.

Comment: Thanks  @akshay khale for your suggestion, but wouldn't array_unique do the opposite of what i need. I need to keep the duplicate values in the rate array. Or if you can give me an example of how i could use it to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement don't depends on `$a` and `$b` so why not to take it out from foreach loop? There is no need to ask database for the same data every time in the loop.

Then you can replace this code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row_rate[] =  $row["rate"];
}
```

with this code

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row_rate[$row["categories"]] =  $row["rate"];
}
```

and then add this code

```
$result_rate = []; //or array() - depends on your PHP version
foreach ($pcategories as $pcat) {
    $result_rate[] =  $row_rate[$pcat];
}
```

Now you have a `$result_rate` array coresponding to your input categories array, so you can replace this code

```
$rate_row[] = $row_rate[$a];
```

with this code

```
$row_rate[] = $result_rate[$a];
```

Here you are the full suggested code:

```
$qty=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qty'];
$pcategories=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pcategories'];

<?php // Get the duty rate based on the product categorie user selected 
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","customs") or  `enter code here`die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$sql = " SELECT `categories`, `rate`
         FROM `lt_products`
         WHERE `categories` IN ('".implode("','",$pcategories)."')
         ORDER BY FIELD(categories, '".implode("','",$pcategories)."')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row_rate[$row["categories"]] =  $row["rate"];
}

$result_rate = []; //or array() - depends on your PHP version
foreach ($pcategories as $pcat) {
    $result_rate[] =  $row_rate[$pcat];
}

$rate_row = []; //or array() - depends on your PHP version
<?php foreach($qty as $a => $b){
    $rate_row[] = $result_rate[$a];
?>
```